# I want my Game to be at the bottom not at the top?

Tags: html, css

I have a school project where i want to programm a Gaming site but the game i copied from another website is always at the top can you help me to bring it down ?
I want the Game to be in the Center of the Website under the Hotbar :)
HTML CODE:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Games</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nav.css">
        <style>
    canvas {
        border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="startGame()">
         <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Aventure Games</a></li>
                <li><a href="">1vs1 Games</a></li>
                <li id="logo"><img src="src/logogif.gif" style="width:300px;"></li>
                <li><a href="">Other Categories</a></li>
                <li><a href="">About us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <article>
            <h1>Games</h1>
            <p>content bla bla</p>
        </article>


        <p class="flappybird">
        <script>

    var myGamePiece;
    var myObstacles = [];
    var myScore;

    function startGame() {
        myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);
        myGamePiece.gravity = 0.05;
        myScore = new component("30px", "Consolas", "black", 280, 40, "text");
        myGameArea.start();
    }

    var myGameArea = {
        canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
        start : function() {
            this.canvas.width = 480;
            this.canvas.height = 270;
            this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
            document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
            this.frameNo = 0;
            this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
            },
        clear : function() {
            this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
        }
    }

    function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
        this.type = type;
        this.score = 0;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.speedX = 0;
        this.speedY = 0;    
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.gravity = 0;
        this.gravitySpeed = 0;
        this.update = function() {
            ctx = myGameArea.context;
            if (this.type == "text") {
                ctx.font = this.width + " " + this.height;
                ctx.fillStyle = color;
                ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
            } else {
                ctx.fillStyle = color;
                ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
            }
        }
        this.newPos = function() {
            this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
            this.x += this.speedX;
            this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;
            this.hitBottom();
        }
        this.hitBottom = function() {
            var rockbottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
            if (this.y > rockbottom) {
                this.y = rockbottom;
                this.gravitySpeed = 0;
            }
        }
        this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
            var myleft = this.x;
            var myright = this.x + (this.width);
            var mytop = this.y;
            var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
            var otherleft = otherobj.x;
            var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
            var othertop = otherobj.y;
            var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
            var crash = true;
            if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
                crash = false;
            }
            return crash;
        }
    }

    function updateGameArea() {
        var x, height, gap, minHeight, maxHeight, minGap, maxGap;
        for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
            if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacles[i])) {
                return;
            } 
        }
        myGameArea.clear();
        myGameArea.frameNo += 1;
        if (myGameArea.frameNo == 1 || everyinterval(150)) {
            x = myGameArea.canvas.width;
            minHeight = 20;
            maxHeight = 200;
            height = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxHeight-minHeight+1)+minHeight);
            minGap = 50;
            maxGap = 200;
            gap = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxGap-minGap+1)+minGap);
            myObstacles.push(new component(10, height, "green", x, 0));
            myObstacles.push(new component(10, x - height - gap, "green", x, height + gap));
        }
        for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
            myObstacles[i].x += -1;
            myObstacles[i].update();
        }
        myScore.text="SCORE: " + myGameArea.frameNo;
        myScore.update();
        myGamePiece.newPos();
        myGamePiece.update();
    }

    function everyinterval(n) {
        if ((myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {return true;}
        return false;
    }

    function accelerate(n) {
        myGamePiece.gravity = n;
    }
    </script>
    <br>
    <button onmousedown="accelerate(-0.2)" onmouseup="accelerate(0.05)">ACCELERATE</button>
    <p>Use the ACCELERATE button to stay in the air</p>
    <p>How long can you stay alive?</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS CODE:

```
*{

        margin: 0px;
        background-color:darkred;
    }
    .nav{
        height: 100px;
    }

    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
        /*padding-left: 30%;
        padding-right: 30%;*/
        /*overflow: hidden;*/
        background-color: gray;
        height:70px;
    }

    li {
        /*float: left;*/
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        margin: 0 -2px;

    }

    li a {
        display: block;
        font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: darkred;
    }
    #logo {
        /*display: block;*/
        font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        background-color: black;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }   
    #logo img{
        display: block;
    }

    li a:hover {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
    }

    }
    p{font-family:Tahoma;}

    article {
        padding-left: 12px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got to define the correct place you want to insert your new element, in your case the canvas.
In your code snippet below, you tell the canvas to be placed before the first child node of the document body.

```
document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
```

You need to specify an element to place it before, below it's looking for the first element with the class name flappybird.

```
document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.getElementsByClassName("flappybird")[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much This helped me alot